# Python: issues understanding magicmock with unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, magicmock

Here is my class:

```
class WorkflowsCloudant(cloudant.Account):

    def __init__(self, account_id):
        super(WorkflowsCloudant, self).__init__(settings.COUCH_DB_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                                auth=(settings.COUCH_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.COUCH_PRIVATE_KEY))
        self.db = self.database(settings.COUCH_DB_NAME)
        self.account_id = account_id

    def get_by_id(self, key, design='by_workflow_id', view='by_workflow_id', limit=None):
        params = dict(key=key, include_docs=True, limit=limit)
        docs = self.db.design(design).view(view, params=params)

        if limit is 1:
            doc = [doc['doc'] for doc in docs]

            if doc:
                workflow = doc[0]

                if workflow.get("account_id") != self.account_id:
                    raise InvalidAccount("Invalid Account")

                return workflow
            else:
                raise NotFound("Autoresponder Cannot Be Found")

        return docs
```

Here is my test:

```
def test_get_by_id_single_invalid_account(self):
    self.klass.account_id = 200
    self.klass.db = mock.MagicMock()
    self.klass.db.design.return_value.view.return_value = [{
        'doc': test_workflow()
    }]
    # wc.get_by_id = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=InvalidAccount("Invalid Account"))
    with self.assertRaises(InvalidAccount("Invalid Account")) as context:
        self.klass.get_by_id('workflow_id', limit=1)

    self.assertEqual('Invalid Account', str(context.exception))
```

I'm trying to get the above test to simple raise the exception of `InvalidAccount` but I'm unsure how to mock out the `self.db.design.view` response. That's what's causing my test to fail because it's trying to make a *real* call out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
def test_get_by_id_single_invalid_account(self):
    self.klass.account_id = 200
    self.klass.db = mock.MagicMock()
    self.klass.db.design = mock.MagicMock()
    view_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    view_mock.return_value =[{
        'doc': test_workflow()
    }]
    self.klass.db.design.return_value.view = view_mock 
    # wc.get_by_id = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=InvalidAccount("Invalid Account"))
    with self.assertRaises(InvalidAccount("Invalid Account")) as context:
        self.klass.get_by_id('workflow_id', limit=1)

    self.assertEqual('Invalid Account', str(context.exception))
```

Comment: That's gotten me closer! For some reason the exception of `NotFound` is being thrown... Might be because the of the way something is mocked up

Comment: Figured it out! Instead of `self.klass.db.design.return_value = view_mock` it was `self.klass.db.design.return_value.view = view_mock`

Comment: @Ah, sorry about that. I'll edit my answer to reflect the correction.